# How to save data under AppData\Roaming instead of AppData\Local\Packages

Tags: c#, windows, appdata, appx

Im developing a WPF aplication that saves some json under AppData\Roaming\MyAppFolder. During testing in VS2017 all was going as planned.

I generated the.appx for my project, installed and runned to see that no data was bing saved where I expected.
After using procmon I found out that the data was actually being saved under AppData\Local\Packages\Myapp_pn7t59nnjk55e\LocalCache\Roaming

Im using `Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.ApplicationData)` to get the folder path.

1. Why exactly it changes when I run my app after installing using .appx?
2. Is there a way to actually save under AppData\Roaming?
3. Should I actually care about it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The data is saved in the right location and your app will be able to read/load it without any problems.

That's where Windows 10 redirects AppData for modern applications, i.e. apps deployed using an appx package.

Comment: Well that actually address all my questions, thanks.